# Go variable initilization syntax

Tags: go

I notice two styles of initializing a struct type variable in Go code examples but I don't understand when to use each.

Style 1:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Msg struct {
  value string
}

func NewMsg(value string) (Msg) {
  return Msg{value}
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

  var helloMsg Msg
  helloMsg = NewMsg("oi")

  fmt.Println("Hello, ", helloMsg.value)
}
```

Style 2:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Msg struct {
  value string
}

func NewMsg(value string) (Msg) {
  return Msg{value}
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

  var helloMsg Msg
  {
     helloMsg = NewMsg("oi")
  }

  fmt.Println("Hello, ", helloMsg.value)
}
```

The first style is a simples variable initilization but the second is more obscure to me. What the curly braces do? Why should I use the second form?

**EDIT:**

For more context on the question, it arrised from this sample code of the Go Kit library: https://github.com/go-kit/kit/blob/master/examples/profilesvc/cmd/profilesvc/main.go

Comment: There are no differences between initialization styles. It is just a difference in structuring code and putting a line in block. I think you wanted to ask about `var x Type` and `x := y`

Comment: The author of the linked code use blocks to group statements. It can be used anywhere, not only with initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What the curly braces do?

They denote a code block. You use code blocks when you want to restrict scope of an identifier (to that block). Here it doesn't make sense, indeed, because you only have one identifier and it's from the outer scope.

Some reading:

- [Scopes in Go](https://medium.com/golangspec/scopes-in-go-a6042bb4298c)
- [Blocks in Go](https://medium.com/golangspec/blocks-in-go-2f68768868f6)

Comment: In this scope, they do not act as code blocks but rather for grouping multiple variables of same type( similar to slices).

Comment: @djtastatur: incorrect. Nothing to do with "same type". It's just a code block. https://play.golang.org/p/yAY0tKjksy2

Comment: There's no particular reason to use a code block in this context. No variables are declared inside the block, so you could omit the braces with no change of meaning. But the syntax is deceptively similar to an initialization like this: `helloMsg := Msg{ value: "oi" }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the difference between these two styles.
They're totally the same.

`{}` this defines scope codes, and some variables declared inside it can only be used inside that scope.
But if you declare `helloMsg` outside and do `=` inside the `{}` block. 'helloMsg' hasn't been scoped.

So, these two formatted style are totally the same.